# how to use fetch to store json data in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

what's wrong with my logic?

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        movies: {}
    },
    created() {
        fetch('movie_db.json')
        .then(response => { response.json();})
        .then(moviedb => { this.movies = moviedb; })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
})
```

I'm using fetch and then after promise is resolved. I'm saying push to movies but `app.movies` is undefined

Comment: I think on the first then you are not returning `{ response.json() }` either make it `{ return response.json() }` or remove curly brackets `response => response.json()`. :)

Comment: oh shit yaa....so dumb of me. I'm not returning json object from with those {}